# FileSystemWatcher - How to pipe output to text file?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am using the FileSystemWatcher Class.  I am trying to pipe the output to a text file.  I have added the `StreamWriter fileWriter = new StreamWriter("test.txt");` but nothing is output to the file!  Where am I going wrong?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string dirPath = "C:\\";

        FileSystemWatcher fileWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher(dirPath);
        fileWatcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
        fileWatcher.Filter = "*.exe";
        // fileWatcher.Filter = "C:\\$Recycle.Bin";
        //  fileWatcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(FileWatcher_Changed);
        fileWatcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(FileWatcher_Created);
        //  fileWatcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(FileWatcher_Deleted);
        //  fileWatcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(FileWatcher_Renamed);
        fileWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        StreamWriter fileWriter = new StreamWriter("test.txt");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't shown any code that would actually write anything...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call

```
fileWriter.Write(data);
```

Additionally, you should wrap it up like this:

```
using(StreamWriter fileWriter = new StreamWriter("test.txt"))
{
    fileWriter.Write(data);
    fileWriter.Flush(); // maybe not necessary
}
```

This will write data to the filesystem and it should trigger your FileSystemWatcher object.

**edit -- inplace example**

```
class Program
{    
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string dirPath = "C:\\";
        FileSystemWatcher fileWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher(dirPath); 
        fileWatcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;  
        fileWatcher.Filter = "*.exe";    
        // fileWatcher.Filter = "C:\\$Recycle.Bin";   
        //  fileWatcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(FileWatcher_Changed);   
        fileWatcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(FileWatcher_Created);    
        //  fileWatcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(FileWatcher_Deleted);  
        //  fileWatcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(FileWatcher_Renamed);    
        fileWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;      

        // updated code
        using(StreamWriter fileWriter = new StreamWriter("test.txt"))
        {
            var data = true;
            fileWriter.Write(data);
        }

        Console.ReadKey(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: It is indeed unnecessary to flush the stream before disposing it.

Comment: @Nate, many thanks, thats much clearer, but I get one error: The name 'FileWatcher_Created' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @Michael glad to hear it. Good luck.

Comment: @Nate, it only outputs "true" in the test.txt file :S

Comment: @Michael -- yes, you can change that to whatever you want, its just an example. The `StreamWriter.Write();` method has many overloads that take different parameters.

Comment: @Nate Ahh, I see, though I have this statement that outputs to the console screen:         `static void FileWatcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("C:\\" + e.Name);
        }` Is it possible to output the result from this statement?

Comment: @Nate I tried: `fileWriter.WriteLine(e.OldName + " was renamed to " + e.Name)(data);` but no luck :(

Comment: Try something like `fileWriter.Write(e.OldName + " was renamed to " + e.Name + Environment.NewLine);`

Comment: @Nate that throws the same error I got: The name 'e' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Where are you defining `e`? I'm assuming the code sample you provided was dumbed down. If that is truely your entire code, there is no `e` object defined at the same scope that `fileWriter` is defined and that error is to be expected.

Comment: @Nate "e" is defined later on, I think that's the problem

Answer (score 3):

The code that actually writes to the output stream needs to be inside the `FileWatcher_Created` event handler. You can only write out that a file was created in the code that runs when a file is created.

That means that the event handler needs access to the `StreamWriter` you've created, or else it needs to open the output file itself, write a value, and then close it every time the event fires.

Since you can't pass the `StreamWriter` to the event handler as an argument, the only way to give the event handler access to it is to make it a class-level variable, which you can't do from a static `Main` method. You'll probably have to create a class to hold both the `FileSystemWatcher` and the `StreamWriter`, and just instantiate that class from the `Main` method.

**But Wait, There's More!**

What if you're in the process of writing to the StreamWriter, and another file gets created at that exact moment? You can't have two threads writing to a single StreamWriter at the same time, or Bad Things are inevitable. So you'll need to protect access to the StreamWriter using some sort of locking.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just use [Log4Net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/index.html) and not worry about thread safety or any of the other gory details.

Put this in your AssemblyInfo.cs:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile="Log4Net.config",Watch=true)]
```

Every class that's going to log something needs a logger. Put this in each such class definition:

```
private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger( MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType ) ;
```

The reason for the above is that it identifies each logger by its containing type. Your log4net.config can filter/route/configure logging by logger, so by doing it this way, you get a great deal of control over the logging. You can, say, dial up the logging verbosity on a particular class that appears to be misbehaving, whilst leaving the rest of the application only logging stuff at, say, the ERROR and FATAL levels.

You can log a message via one of the ILog methods (just like `Console.WriteLine()` or `string.Format()`:

```
Log.InfoFormat( "some-format-string" , ... ) ;
```

Set up your log4net.config file so it looks something like this:

```
<log4net>

  <appender name="Console" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <!-- Pattern to output the caller's file name and line number -->
      <conversionPattern value="%5level [%thread] (%file:%line) - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file               value="example.log" />
    <appendToFile       value="true"        />
    <maximumFileSize    value="100KB"       />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="2"           />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%level %thread %logger - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <root>
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="Console" />
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
  </root>

</log4net>
```

And you'll logging to the console and to a file. Log4Net will take care of log file rollover and all the icky bits.